# When I run any "rake" command, I get: uninitialized constant Gem::Specification::PLATFORM_CROSS_TARGETS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

After installing RedCloth, I can not run any "rake" -tasks.

I get:

> rake aborted!
>   uninitialized constant Gem::Specification::PLATFORM_CROSS_TARGETS

[Here's output](http://pastie.org/568614) of **rake routes --trace**

Versions:

- Rake - 0.8.4
- Rails - 2.3.2
- Ruby - 1.8.7
- RedCloth - 4.2.2
- Gem - 1.3.5

**the Rakefile:**

```
require(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'config', 'boot'))

require 'rake'
require 'rake/testtask'
require 'rake/rdoctask'

require 'tasks/rails'`
```

Anyone else had the same problem? Any solutions?

Thanks Stackoverflow.

**edit:**
added line:

```
Gem::Specification::PLATFORM_CROSS_TARGETS = ["aix", "cygwin", "darwin", "freebsd", "hpux", "java", "linux", "mingw", "mswin", "netbsdelf", "openbsd", "solaris", "_platform", "jruby"]
```

to file **./vendor/plugins/redcloth/lib/tasks/pureruby.rake** and I think that fixed it. Don't know if that was the best solution.. but it works.

Answer (score -2):

I can't say 100% sure, but based on the information you have set forth and the general look of the message you are putting on the screen, it sounds like you are having a problem.

Comment: I have no idea why, but I really agree with this post.